# How do you open a program with a .application extension on a mac?

Tags: .net, macos, clickonce

I'm doing some development work that involves making use of an API from software that generally runs on Windows. I had to change the user agent within Safari to Microsoft Edge just to be able to access the software, when I do it downloads a file with a .application file extension, that from what I've read is meant to be opened with the ClickOnce through Microsoft. How would I run this software on a Mac? Or do I need to create some kind of Windows partition? Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why would you even think you would be able to run Windows-specific software on a Mac?

Comment: You can sometimes run windows software through applications like Wine, my question was meant generally as what is the best way to run this specific type of software on my machine, either via a program like Wine or with a parallel operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Windows|Mac|Android|... compiled software runs on Windows|Mac|Android...

*If* you are compiling from source, using an interpreted language, or using software compiled for a virtual machine such as the Java Virtual Machine then the software *may* run on a different platform to the one it was developed on though you may need to change some bits, e.g. bits that interface to the OS or GUI.

Your having to spoof a Windows browser just to get the software strongly suggests it is intended for the Windows platform *only*. An “API [that] runs on Windows” is also a big clue you need Windows, assuming you've looked for and failed to find a Mac version of the API.

You can run Windows software under MacOS by using virtual machine software – take a look at VMWare Fusion (commercial, free version available), Parallels Desktop (commercial) and Virtual Box (free) – or by using Apple’s "BootCamp". All these solutions require you to have a copy of Windows to install, they don't come with one.

If you have access to source, or have a VM binary, take a look at Microsoft’s Visual Studio for Mac & .Net Core – if the language is supported then you might be a similar position to using Java/JVM and the software *may* be able to be compiled or run, but simply being “.Net” doesn’t mean it will.